# Matrix transpose multiplication

Tags: matrix, cvx

In CVX, I encounter a problem. I want to multiply a Matrix of 2x4 with its transpose. I know the result must be positive definite. However, it couldn't let me do the multiplication directly. Says: Disciplined convex programming error:Only scalar quadratic forms can be specified in CVX. What can I do?

`cvx_begin
    variable power_allocation(length(anchor_coordinate.x),1)
    minimize sum(power_allocation)
    subject to
    Matrix = process_matrix_inv'*(observation_matrix(:,:,t*n+1)'*diag(power_allocation.*path_loss(:,t*n+1))*
observation_matrix(:,:,t*n+1)+prior_infor(:,:,t*n))*process_matrix_inv;
    A = Matrix(1:2,3:6)*D*Matrix(1:2,3:6)';
    trace_inv(Matrix(1:2,1:2)-A) <= MSE_limit;
    power_allocation <= power_max;
    power_allocation >= power_min;
    cvx_end`

Comment: the matrix D is a symmetrical matrix.

Comment: I tone the end of the post down a bit.

Comment: As a small remark, the product of a matrix and its transpose doesn't have to be positive definite. It can be positive semidefinite. Try, for example, with a matrix that has a zero column, or is in fact entirely composed of zeros.

Answer (score 4):

In CVX, you can use

**quad_form(A*x-b,Q)**

to implement

$
(Ax-b)^{T}Q(Ax-b)
$

See the section of the manual on scalar quadratic forms.

Comment: Dear professor, thank you for your reply. However, in my case, the (A*x-b) part is a tensor with 2*4 scale. And in CVX, it only permits me to input a vector. How could I fix that ?

Comment: And all I want is to represent the sum of first two elements in the trace line of an inverse of Matrix.